# unpacking class variables as a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

Let's say I have an "array"

```
self.memory = [None] * 10000
```

now let's say I have a class like so:

```
class Process:
  def __init__(self, process_id, state, priority):
    self.process_id = process_id
    self.state = state
    self.priority = priority
  def operation_that_adds_class_variables(self):
    if self.priority > 5:
      self.urgency = 'HIGH'
    else:
      self.urgency = 'LOW'
```

I do a few things to `memory`, now it has some values in it. I find the first occurrence of `None` and want to put a `Process` there. However, I want that instance of the class to unpack its initialized `self` variables

```
def CreateProcess(process_id, state, priority):
  print 'memory before create process'
  print self.memory
  index = self.memory.index(None)
  p = Process(process_id, state, priority)
  ready_queue.append(p)
  self.memory[index] = #unpack p, with offsets in memory
  print 'memory after create process'
  print self.memory
```

essentially, here is what I am expecting.

```
Memory before create process:
[1, 2, 3, 4, None, None, None, None ...]
Memory after create process
[1, 2, 3, 4, PROCESS_1, states['pending'], 3, 'HIGH URGENCY', ...]
```

is this achievable easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use slice assignment:

```
self.memory[index:index + 4] = p.process_id, p.state, p.priority, p.urgency
```

Note that this *can* expand `self.memory`; you may want to do a bounds check first:

```
if index <= len(self.memory) - 4:
```

Demo:

```
>>> memory = [1, 2, 3, 4, None, None, None, None]
>>> index = memory.index(None)
>>> memory[index:index + 4] = 'foo', 'bar', 'spam', 'eggs'
>>> memory
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'foo', 'bar', 'spam', 'eggs']
```

To support a variable number of attributes, you could expand your `Process` class to track what attributes need to be included:

```
class Process:
    urgency = None

    def __init__(self, process_id, state, priority):
        self.process_id = process_id
        self.state = state
        self.priority = priority

    def operation_that_adds_class_variables(self):
        if self.priority > 5:
            self.urgency = 'HIGH'
        else:
            self.urgency = 'LOW'

    @property
    def memory_values(self):
        res = (self.process_id, self.state, self.priority)
        if self.urgency is not None:
            return res + (self.urgency,)
        return res
```

then store the result of that in your 'memory':

```
proc_memory = p.memory_values
if index <= len(self.memory) - len(proc_memory):
    self.memory[index:index + len(proc_memory)] = proc_memory
```

You cannot arbitrarily list attributes, because the instance `__dict__` object holding attributes is a dictionary; it has no order. You'll have to specify an order yourself.

Comment: There is, however, a problem with that. Some variables are added sometimes. Eg, urgency may not always be called. (probably wasn't clear in my question though).